# Ошибка в компиляции Kotlin-файла, в "it" и в делегациях

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Я имею ошибки в компиляции Kotlin, но при этом IntelliJ IDEA при просмотре файла говорит, что ошибок нет, а появляются они только в компиляции.
Ошибки, полученные мной:

```
C:\Users\���������\IdeaProjects\CororoPlugins\Chat\src\main\kotlin\chat\Chat.kt: (19, 14): Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Chat, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable: 
C:\Users\���������\IdeaProjects\CororoPlugins\Chat\src\main\kotlin\chat\Chat.kt: (20, 14): Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Chat, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable: 
C:\Users\���������\IdeaProjects\CororoPlugins\Chat\src\main\kotlin\chat\Chat.kt: (77, 41): Unresolved reference: it
```

... там ещё много ошибок с it
Части кода, на которые ругается:
19-20 строки:

```
val c by ulazy { ChatConfig(config) }
val m by ulazy { ChatMessages(config.getConfigurationSection("messages")) }
```

76-77 строки:

```
event.recipients.removeAll { it in disabledGlobalChat }
            (c.globalChat.firstOrNull { it.first in groups } ?: c.globalChat.last()).second
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
}

version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/")
        content {
            includeGroup("org.bukkit")
            includeGroup("org.spigotmc")
        }
    }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
        name = "bungeecord-repo"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    compileOnly(files("libs/Lib.jar"))
    compileOnly(files("libs/PermissionsEx-1.23.4.jar"))
    compileOnly("net.md-5:bungeecord-chat:1.12-SNAPSHOT")
    compileOnly("org.bukkit:bukkit:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    compileOnly("org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks {
    jar {
        doFirst {
            from({
                configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и полные ошибки, полученные мной: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZV4f.png
Как фиксить?

Comment: что такое ulazy, какая-то своя реализация lazy? делегаты должны иметь определённые функции, вроде той, что написана в сообщении `getValue(Chat, KProperty<*>)`

Answer (score 0):

У Вас путь не подходит для этого. Крайне нежелательно класть проекты в папку, путь к которой не на латинице. Попробуйте для начала переместить проект, например, в корень диска и открыть оттуда. После этого сделайте InvalidateCache/Restart.